# Determining how interactive web map was created?

Tags: web-mapping

I found this on github, http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html, with no map credits.

Does anyone know how this interactive web map was created?

I need to make a map in this style and cannot find out which program to use or if it requires coding to create.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It uses the d3.js library.  Go to their website, click on "Examples" and the link you provided is their "Symbol Map" example:

https://d3js.org

It requires some coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get information about how an arbitrary website (or the map, visualization etc. they contain) was created, it is helpful to view the source code of this site.
In most browsers, you can to this, by a "right click" on the page and then select "View Source".

The source code of your site looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.csv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.geo.js"></script>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

If you see script-tags you might find out, which javascript library was used to create the visualization.

Other maps might origin from web map services (WMS), they are often included as images.
Some of the most common visualization libraries (for maps) are OpenLayers, Leaflet, GoogeMaps API and also d3js.